# SQL Self Left Join Challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
ManufacturerID   ProductID     Price    Region
==============================================
100              1             12.00    A
100              2             20.00    A
100              3             25.00    A
100              4             30.00    B
101              1             15.00    A
101              2             20.00    A
101              4             30.00    B
```

I want to get a query result that compares 2 different manufacturers to look like this:

```
ProductID     Price1    Price2    Region
=========================================================================
1             12.00     15.00     A
2             20.00     20.00     A
3             25.00     null      A
4             30.00     30.00     B
```

I try to use left join on the same table:

```
SELECT ProductID, a.Price AS Price1, b.Price AS Price2, a.Region
FROM   table1 a 
       LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID AND a.ManufacturerID = 100
WHERE  b.ManufacturerID = 101
```

but this doesn't give me the missing product (ID:4) from Manufacturer 101. What am I missing?

Comment: `SQL Self Left Join Challenge`.. you're kidding right ?

Comment: You turned it into an inner join with your where clause  http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't know in advance which product will be missing, for example manufacturer A might be missing product 3 and manufacture B missing product 8, you need a `FULL OUTER` join, if you want to do this with a join (Gordon provided a different way to go).

I assumed that the `(ManufacturerID ,ProductID, Region)` combination has a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ProductID, b.ProductID) AS ProductID, 
       a.Price AS Price1, 
       b.Price AS Price2, 
       COALESCE(a.Region, b.Region) AS Region
FROM   
       ( SELECT ProductID, Price, Region
         FROM table1
         WHERE ManufacturerID = 100
       ) AS a
    FULL JOIN 
       ( SELECT ProductID, Price, Region
         FROM table1
         WHERE ManufacturerID = 101
       ) AS b
           ON  a.ProductID = b.ProductID 
           AND a.Region = b.Region      -- not sure if you need this line
;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7df97/18)** (thnx @Thomas)

Comment: Voted ypercube's answer since I do have this scenario and his solution fits the bill.

Answer (score 3):

You have `a.ManufacturerID` and `b.ManufacturerID` the wrong way round in the `on` and `where` clauses - try:

```
SELECT ProductID, a.Price AS Price1, b.Price AS Price2, a.Region
FROM   table1 a 
       LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID AND b.ManufacturerID = 101
WHERE  a.ManufacturerID = 100
```

Comment: And what if another product is produced by manufacturer 101 but not by 100?

Comment: Mark, thanks for the reply. I think I've probably overthought this too much so I missed the obvious. Thanks.

Comment: ypercube, that's a good question and I do have that scenario. What do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your reply, too. I did try your solution and it worked. However, I think ypercube's is more complete so I voted his solution as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using aggregation, rather than a join:

```
select ProductId,
       MAX(case when ManufacturerId = 100 then Price end) as Price1,
       MAX(case when ManufacturerId = 101 then Price end) as Price2,
       Region
from table1
where ManufacturerId in (100, 101)
group by ProductId, Region;
```